# What is an Istio external service？

Tags: kubernetes, istio

I have never understood what is an external Istio service. Is it an application external to kubernetes, or is it an application that does not inject a sidecar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are three kinds of configuration for external services: HTTP, TLS and TCP.

In many cases, not all the parts of a microservices-based application reside in a service mesh or ingress. Sometimes, the microservices-based applications use functionality provided by legacy systems that reside outside the mesh.

You would like to migrate these systems to the service mesh gradually. Until these systems are migrated, they must be accessed by the applications inside the mesh. In other cases, the applications use web services provided by third parties.

This is one nice example to understand : https://istio.io/blog/2018/egress-https/

Comment: Thank you for your answer，I saw the link you gave me and also read this link: https://istio.io/blog/2018/egress-tcp/. I noticed a sentence:
`Note that the MySQL database is outside the Istio service mesh, or more precisely outside the Kubernetes cluster. The boundary of the service mesh is marked by a dashed line.`.
Does it mean that external applications are applications that are not deployed on the Kubernetes cluster?

Comment: yes probably you can say that which is outside the kubernetes cluster as i have mentioned example of micro-service. you can use it to access the any public service inside the cluster.

Comment: I'd say both answers are correct, there's in-cluster services that we don't need/want to be part of the mesh, and also off-cluster services, that could encompass several kinds again (databases, 3rd party APIs, etc.). All of that can be seen as external services, there's not a single type of usage.